# How can I print a matrix using numpy without ellipsis in the middle?

Tags: numpy, matrix

I made a matrix 12x8 to use it as a gameboard with numpy but when I try to print it the matrix is printed incomplete (with ellipsis in the middle).
My real question is how can I print it correctly.
Thanks.

Comment: Cast it as a list of lists and print that

Comment: 12x8 isn't big enough to trigger summarization under default settings, so you're doing something else wrong besides expecting the string representation of an array to show the whole thing.

Comment: A [short code sample that exhibits this behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be quite helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [`np.set_printoptions()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) to control summarization when printing.